# How to send dynamic modal form fields to django

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, bootstrap-4

I'm creating dynamic modal form field and I want to send generated field value to django but just one field is sent to my django server.
I woner if this is caused by the fact the input field have the same  name.
Any suggestion please ?

```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields = 10;
var wrapper = $(".container1");
var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

var x = 1;
$(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
    } else {
        alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
})
```

});

```
                      <div class="modal fade" id="multipleset{{ecriture.id_ecriture}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
                             <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                   <div class="modal-header">
                                      <h6 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ajouter une &eacute;criture</h6>
                                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                      </button>
                                   </div>

                                  <form action="{% url 'multipleset' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                      <div class="container1">
                                          <button class="add_form_field">Add New Field &nbsp;
                                            <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span>
                                          </button>
                                          <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
                                    </div>
                                  </form>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the name of the input name dynamically like given below. And I think this should do the trick. (Didn't tested) Please give it a try.

```
$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext'+x+'"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
```